# 403 Error creating dataSource for com.google.blood_pressure in Google Fit REST API

Tags: google-oauth, google-fit, google-fit-api

**Goal:**

I have a simple web application where I submit my Blood Pressure and Heart Rate measurements.
Now I'd like to submit these measurements to my Google Fit Account.

I tried Googles tutorial: https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/write-bp-data

**OAuth2 Setup**

I created new credentials in one of my existing Cloud Console Projects. And then requested a new authorization code using the following scopes (The project is in Testing State and my account is registered as tester):

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.write

Requesting the token returns the following response:

```
{
    "access_token": "ya29.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "refresh_token": "1//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.write",
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

As you can see, both write scopes are granted.
Additionally, if I check the permissions in my Google Account, both scopes are set.

**Create dataSource**

Now I create two dataSources (one for com.google.heart_rate.bpm and one for com.google.blood_pressure).
creating the Heart Rate dataSource works as expected, but creating a dataSource for Blood Pressure returns a **403 PERMISSION_DENIED** Error:

Request (POST https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources)

```
{
    "dataStreamName": "BPA-BloodPressure",
    "type": "raw",
    "application": {
        "detailsUrl": "https://aaa.bbb.ccc",
        "name": "Blood Pressure App",
        "version": "1"
    },
    "dataType": {
        "name": "com.google.blood_pressure"
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Scope not included to modify data of type com.google.blood_pressure. Possible scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.write",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Scope not included to modify data of type com.google.blood_pressure. Possible scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.write",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

The Google Fit REST API tells me that the Scope **fitness.blood_pressure.write** is missing, but as you can see the Scope is given for the used access token.

**Notes**

- I am working with Postman to test all requests. Later a Java/Groovy or PHP backend will used.
- I also tried with read and write scopes for both data types.
- I can see my app with both write scopes in Google Fit under "Connected apps".

Comment: Double check that the access token you are using is the one with the corect permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Change dataType name to "fitness.blood_pressure" instead of "com.google.blood_pressure"

The body will be like this.

```
{
    "dataStreamName": "BPA-BloodPressure",
    "type": "raw",
    "application": {
        "detailsUrl": "https://aaa.bbb.ccc",
        "name": "Blood Pressure App",
        "version": "1"
    },
    "dataType": {
        "name": "fitness.blood_pressure"
    }
}
```